# How to search files starts by X in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a script who get files older than X date, the problem is when i do some search for a directory, the script take all the files older than X, i need to specify just files start with Back* not all the files :/

```
from sys import argv
import os, time

script, dir, age = argv
print "Searching in directory %s for file older than %s day(s)" % (str(argv[1]), str(argv[2]))

#convert age to sec. 1 day = 24*60*60
age = int(age)*86400

for file in os.listdir(dir):
    now = time.time()
    filepath = os.path.join(dir, file)
    modified = os.stat(filepath).st_mtime
    if modified < now - age:
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            #print (filepath)
            print 'Result : %s (%s)' % (file, str(argv[2]))
```

Comment: Show us the script, otherwise we can't really help you

Comment: Can you check again, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a check whether the filename starts with "Back", for example as:

```py
if (os.path.isfile(filepath)
    and modified < now - age
    and os.path.basename(filepath).startswith("Back")):
  print 'Result : %s (%s)' % (file, str(argv[2]))
```

alternatively, you can replace `os.path.basename(filepath)` with just `file`, if you are not trying to search the directory recursively.